# Consumir API local desde angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, express, cors

Buenas tardes estimados,
Estaba intentando hacer un pequeño ejercicio creando un API local y luego consumirla a través de Angular.
El API esta hecha en NodeJs usando express

Pero se me presenta un pequeño problema, al momento de intentar consumir el API, me aparece un error de CORS bloqueando el acceso.

Estuve investigando en varios sitios por la solución y en todos dicen que se debe configurar un proxy para esto, ahora mi duda es, el proxy es la única manera de quitar el error de cors?

Intentaba ver otra forma sin tener que usar proxy.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: para evitar el bloqueo cors deben coincidir el protocolo, servidor y puerto. hay varias formas de testearlo local. la mas sencilla es que el api esté en una subcarpeta ( y que angular no intente rutear ) o en express meter un middleware para que [acepte la conexion enviando headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-allow-origin), ahi la mas simple es `npm install cors` de https://github.com/expressjs/cors y [configuras el origin](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors) o lo dejas promiscuo (`*`)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta sería no, el proxy no es la única manera de quitar el cors, también puedes permitir el CORs desde tu backend y de hecho esta sería la forma correcta.

Recuerda que el proxy solo debes usarlo para tus pruebas locales.
Para habilitarlo desde el back para eso debes instalar cors, ejemplo.

Para habilitarlo solo para tu aplicación, debes poner el puerto y dominio.

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200']
}));
```

O puedes habilitarlo para cualquiera con *

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
```

O si de plano quieres tener una whitelist puedes poner algo como lo siguiente;

```
const whitelist = ['http://dom1.com', 'http://dom2.com']
const corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
         if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
             callback(null, true)
         } else {
             callback(new Error())
         }
    }
```

}